# Is it possible to start the various iot-edge modules one by one sequentially? If so, how to do it?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

Is it possible to start the various iot-edge modules one by one sequentially? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no support for starting various modules sequentially in Iot Edge due to various module dependencies and seems to be intentionally done to bring in resiliency. The sequencing may not be of help if any other module your module depends on crashes or is updated. In such cases The IoT Hub SDK will retry operations for you, and you should be able to adjust it's timeouts.
Here is one good reference https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/1105